No output for a "who am i" command
I've been using Ubuntu 24.04 on VirtualBox 7.0.16 on Windows 10 for only 3 days now. I've used several commands on a terminal and they worked fine. But who am i gave no response. But grep [username] /etc/passwd has given the expected response. Why not who am i?

The command who am i I'd expect to give no response; given the args (am i) you used...  You likely meant the command whoami (ie. one word so a different command) which will respond with your $USER

Maybe just try the id command instead.

Your book is rather out of date.
The command who am i (or who mom likes etc.) certainly used to work, and should be equivalent to who -m. For example, the texinfo documentation (info coreutils 'who invocation') says:

   If given two non-option arguments, ‘who’ prints only the entry for
the user running it (determined from its standard input), preceded by
the hostname.  Traditionally, the two arguments given are ‘am i’, as in
‘who am i’.


However in most modern terminal emulators who -m returns nothing. Fundamentally that's because who has to get that information from the utmp entry, and terminal emulators that rely on libvte no longer write pseudoterminal (pts) entries to the utmp file. From apt changelog libvte-2.91-0 for example:


Stop shipping gnome-pty-helper in libvte-2.91-0

no longer shipped by upstream (see bgo#747046).
(this means no utmp/wtmp updating anymore.)




The clearest discussion I can find is this blog entry 'who am i' does not work in recent GNOME-terminal (and MATE-terminal) which includes links to primary sources including this gnome.org bug report.
If you're curious, you should find that it still works in CLI virtual terminals (accessible via Ctrl+Alt+F6 for example) or a pseudo-terminal started via xterm, which doesn't rely on libvte to write the utmp entry:



I think it would probably be useful to add to the answer what the OP probably wants, i.e. whoami or id, and maybe explain the difference.

Wow, well spotted, I had just assumed the OP had misunderstood when someone told them the command is whoami. It would be great if you could explain what the utmp file is and why one would expect a terminal to write to it. I've never heard of this before and I am probably more familiar than the OP is with Linux, so I imagine the OP will be as confused as I am.

@terdon: Familiarity with Linux is not really relevant here, as utmp has nothing to do with the kernel. It is part of the login system. utmp dates back to at least AT&T Unix v6, the first version to be distributed outside AT&T in 1975. Linus Torvalds was six years old at the time.

@terdon thanks for the edit - tbh my knowledge of utmp is minimal, rather than risk saying anything foolish I think linking to the manpage is probably best

It's really not about VTE. I've tried 11 non-VTE-based terminals as shipped by Ubuntu 24.04, using their default configs. 5 of them do utmp logging (foot, konsole, pterm, urxvt, xterm), 6 don't (alacritty, kitty, mlterm, st, terminology, zutty). For VTE-based ones, VTE itself doesn't do utmp logging, but its embedding terminal app can. Here I tested again 11, out of which 1 does utmp logging (guake) and 10 don't (blackbox, gnome-console, gnome-terminal, lxterminal, sakura, terminator, termit, tilda, tilix, xfce4-terminal). [Not sure if any of these supports utmp as a nondefault option.]

man utmp says "The utmp file allows one to discover information about who is currently using the system." One can use the system and not have a single terminal open at a given moment. Some folks believe it's nevertheless expected from a terminal to update this voluntarily maintained and unreliable piece of information (utmp). Others disagree with this, claiming that the terminal is not the point where you log in, and that the terminal is not conceptually different than any other app you might be running and also don't update utmp. As an app developer, don't count on the terminal updating it.

The command who am i I'd expect to give no response; given the args (am i) you used...
You likely meant the command whoami (ie. one word so a different command) which will respond with your $USER
guiverc@d7050-next:~/uwn/issues/837$   whoami
guiverc

versus
guiverc@d7050-next:~/uwn/issues/837$   who am i


ehm not entirely correct ;) who am i assumes -m and that is "If ARG1 ARG2 given, -m presumed: 'am i' or 'mom likes' are usual. " and -m     only hostname and user associated with stdin  so in a TTY it works

$ who am i
chris pts/0 2019-10-21 22:45 (:0.0)   This is an extract of the book I'm using to learn Linux.

who hates you  also works :D

I'm totaly new to Linux hence may not understand some of your comments. But that's OK, since you are trying help me.
